# Textfields don't get selected after reloadData on UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my UITableView I have rows which contain 4 textfields each. After user ends editing couple of things in UITableView datasource are being recalculated, so I need to reload UITableView after edition of textfield. But because tableview is being reloaded, when user touches another textfield to edit while editing the first one, second textfield doesn't get selected. He has to touch it again before it can be edited.

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour? Unfortunately I do need to use reloadData instead of reloadSections or reloadRows methods. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to reload?

Comment: Couple of different sections also need to be updated after edition on textfields finished. Seemed to me as a better solution since almost whole tableview needs to be redisplayed. Also I'm experiencing some weird animation issues with reloadSections method even if I set a UITableViewRowAnimation to None

Comment: Could you get the cells and directly update them? Are you adding rows / sections or changing row heights?

Comment: Adding row may occur during the update process, not necessarily though. Row heights are mutable, but not during this process.

Comment: So you could update cells as required and animate in any new rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing up all the help I received and my own ideas I've gone with the following:

-Delay reload for 0.01 sec so `textFieldDidBeginEditing` gets called

-Then save textfield's tag and cell's index path to variables in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

-Call `reloadData` on tableview

-Call `becomeFirstResponder` on textfield saved with variables

This however caused keyboard hiding for a brief moment as it didn't have any responder during reloading. To resolve that I created a fake textfield in tableview's superview and assigned him as a responder up to a moment when tableview was reloaded to assign back to the textfield that was selected by a user.

Certainly not the cleanest solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Reloading a table view will resign the first responder of the text field or even text view.  You could try this trick if you have multiple changes that need to be made.

```
[[self tableView] beginUpdates]
[[self tableView] endUpdates]
```

Comment: This causes crashes because of number of rows being changed. I used to have a lot of trouble with using this solution, so I just dropped it.

Comment: I'd have to see some code, but there must be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning a `gestureRecognizer` to each field or same one to all fields. Once you capture the `touch` in required field, capture the `tag` and make that field the `firstResponder`.

Comment: Right now I am trying to implement similar solution, but just delaying reload a little bit so didBeginEditing is being called, so no need to actually assign a gestureRecognizer. However I'm not completely happy with this solution. Was hoping there will be some simpler, cleaner solution, but I guess I'll have to stick with it unless something else comes to my mind.

Comment: I seem to be really close to finishing this, however there is a slight problem. When I switch between the textfields there is this brief moment when keyboard hides for like 0.1 second and shows up again. It doesn't look very good.

Comment: are you doing `resignFirstResponder` in `textFieldDidEndEditing`? If yes, that could be the reason for that hide+show of keyboard

Comment: That's what I was looking for when I first noticed this, but no, I don't use it.